# Filter the queryset in Python 3 and jQuery DataTables

Tags: python, django, datatables

I am trying to query on jQuery Datatables list.

Right now I can fetch all records from the table, but I want to fetch records to whom their parent id matches.

For example, users have posts, so in my case it would be fetch posts where user id is lets say 1.

So I am trying to implement same thing for jQuery Datatables.

I can see data is being posted but I can't figure out how to query along with `datatables`, so that `datatables` filters are not affected by this change.

My current code:

```
class PartRequestViewSet(CommonViewset, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = PartRequest.objects.filter(deleted_at=None)
    serializer_class = PartRequestSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        records = request.GET.get('records', None)
        # ID of the part
        part_number_id = request.GET.get('part_number_id', None)

        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None and records is None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now in above code I can get the `part_number_id` from request, but how can I filter records using `filter_queryset()`, so that only parts_requests are given back in datatables where `part_number_id` is 1

### Update

Current helper function `filter_queryset` that is used in above code.

```
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        format = self.request.GET.get('format', None)
        if format == 'datatables':
            self.filter_backends += (DatatablesFilterBackend,)
        else:
            self.filter_backends += (DjangoFilterBackend,)
        for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
            queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did is I added the following lines:

```
 if part_number_id:
     queryset = queryset.filter(part_number_id=part_number_id)
```

so the code looks like this now and it is working great. I'm open to better and more efficient options.

```
class PartRequestViewSet(CommonViewset, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = PartRequest.objects.filter(deleted_at=None)
    serializer_class = PartRequestSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        records = request.GET.get('records', None)
        # ID of the part
        part_number_id = request.GET.get('part_number_id', None)
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        if part_number_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(part_number_id=part_number_id)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None and records is None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `django-filter` extension. In your case it may be something like the following:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer


class PostList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['owner']
```

Then you can use get request like this: `/posts?owner=3`,
where 3 is user id and owner is ForeignKey in Post model to User.

Comment: thankyou for response. i really appreciate your help.
I am new in python, just learning, what is filterset_fields and where would i use it?

if you see my code there is no `filterset_fields`, only is `queryset`.

Comment: `filterset_fields` is array of fields defined in model/serializer you wanna use as a filter. In your case just put a field that is foreign key in `PartRequest` to `User` to `filterset_fields `. No one additional methods aren't required except you intend logic